# get the id of radio button group in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of radio buttons with the name 'periodType'. There is one radio button in that group which behaves the same way as the others, except for the fact that it displays an additional div. How can I get to know when that particular radio button is checked, as the change function below is quite generic for all the radio buttons in the group:

```
  $('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //do something (for all radio buttons)
            //If unique radio button also do this
        }
    }); 

    <input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
```

Comment: i cannot see any div in your html so where is additional div displayed

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a value to your radio inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="periodType" value="one" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" value="two" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" value="three" default>
<input type="radio" name="periodType" value="four" default>
```

and then query that value:

```
$('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'three' && this.checked) {
    //do something (for all radio buttons)
    //If unique radio button also do this
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //do something (for all radio buttons)
            //If unique radio button also do this
           var idval = $(this).attr("id");
           if (idval == "something")
           {
             //do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this. I have added each radio to its own div just to show the behaviour on change. Please let me know if you have any questions.

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .selected{background-color: #fad42e;}
            .notSelected{background-color: #6f6e73;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {


                $('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
                    $(this).parent('div').removeClass();
                    $(this).parent('div').addClass('selected');

                    $('input[name="periodType"]')
                            .parent('div')
                            .not($(this).parent("div"))
                            .each(function(e){
                                $(this).removeClass();
                                $(this).addClass("notSelected");
                            });
                });



            });




        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="periodType" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="periodType" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="periodType" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="periodType" >
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```